# Issue with Error Messages in C# Application when making AJAX Requests to Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis, https

I'm facing a puzzling issue in my C# application, and I'm hoping someone can shed some light on it. Here's the problem:

I have a C# application deployed on IIS, and when I make an AJAX request from a view to a controller using HTTPS, it returns generic error messages with a status code of 400 but without any error message. However, when I make the same request using HTTP, it does return the error message.

I've been struggling with this for several days now, trying to understand why this happens and how to resolve it, but I haven't been successful.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any insights on what might be causing this behavior? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This is the request from the view
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Controller/Action",
data: { datos },
success: function (res) {
////
},
error: function (err) {
alert(err.statusText) //This only shows error on https, but on https it does show the message
});

This is the request from the view

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Controller/Action",
            data: { datos },
            success: function (res) {
                ////
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.statusText) //This only shows error on https, but on https it does show the message
        });
```

This is how the controller returns the error.

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                    Response.StatusDescription =  error.Mensaje;
                    return Json(respuesta, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I already checked and it is at the moment that the ajax request receives the error that returns it generic, the response is correct within the controller.

I want the custom error message returned by the 400 request to also be displayed in HTTPS and not a generic error.

Comment: Show the site bindings please.

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 400 error and please post the your website configuration information in the web.config file.